# SHASUMS AND grep in verifying Ubuntu download

Tags: command-line, grep, checksums, sha256

I'm trying to better understand the use of "SHA256SUMS" and "grep." The Ubuntu verify and authenticate tutorial uses the following term: "sha256sum -c SHA256SUMS 2>&1 | grep OK" to verify the download hasn't been corrupted.

I understand it's checking at the SHA256SUMS file that contains two hash values, one for the Desktop version and one for the Live. The usage worked, and I checked it by manually verifying the hash values.

My question is what is the "SHA256SUMS 2>&1" portion doing?  Also, it appears to be a part of the "SHA256SUMS" command, though I don't see that usage on the man page I use. Then somehow the result is piped to "grep" to pattern-match with no options.

I'd like to understand it well enough to use the technique in verifying that other software downloads haven't been corrupted.

Comment: Related: [What do these symbols “$@”>/dev/null 2>&1" after a command mean?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1059716/what-do-these-symbols-dev-null-21-after-a-command-mean/1059724#1059724)

Comment: The command is `sha256sum -c SHA256SUMS` ; `2>&1` is a *shell redirection* that combines the command's standard error stream `2` with its standard output stream `1` so that both are piped to the `grep` command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `grep` command is just there to clean up the output for you. The hash checker checks against all the disk images, so the grep command keeps things simple.

With grep:

`ubuntu-core-16-amd64.img.xz: OK`

Without grep:

`ubuntu-core-16-amd64.img.xz: OK
sha256sum: ubuntu-core-16-cm3.img.xz: No such file or directory
ubuntu-core-16-cm3.img.xz: FAILED open or read
sha256sum: ubuntu-core-16-dragonboard-410c.img.xz: No such file or directory
ubuntu-core-16-dragonboard-410c.img.xz: FAILED open or read
sha256sum: ubuntu-core-16-dragonboard.img.xz: No such file or directory
ubuntu-core-16-dragonboard.img.xz: FAILED open or read
sha256sum: ubuntu-core-16-i386.img.xz: No such file or directory
ubuntu-core-16-i386.img.xz: FAILED open or read
sha256sum: ubuntu-core-16-pi2.img.xz: No such file or directory
ubuntu-core-16-pi2.img.xz: FAILED open or read
sha256sum: ubuntu-core-16-pi3.img.xz: No such file or directory
ubuntu-core-16-pi3.img.xz: FAILED open or read
sha256sum: WARNING: 6 listed files could not be read`

Update:
Sorry, I missed the `2>&1` part of your question. That portion directs any error messages to the same place as the standard output messages. This page explains that quirky idiom: https://www.brianstorti.com/understanding-shell-script-idiom-redirect/